# associatedValueForKey, unrecognized key

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, nsobject, objective-c-runtime

If I haven't used 'objc_setAssociatedObject' to associate an object/key to an NSObject, and then I call 'objc_getAssociatedObject', is this safe?

I've tested it in the simulator and it doesn't crash, but I want to be sure.

And when I make the call:

```
 objc_setAssociatedObject(self, key, value, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
```

Does the object that I associate with my NSObject get released when my NSObject is dealloc'd? (I'm using ARC).

Comment: Given the way that ARC works, it seems unlikely ARC is inserting `objc_setAssociatedObject` with `nil` or `objc_removeAssociatedObjects` for you - because it would not know where to place those calls.  But I could not find a definitive answer in the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is no association in place, `objc_getAssociatedObject` will return `nil`.

When you associate an object, it will use the semantics supplied in the last argument.  For example, `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN` will retain the object so it is not deallocated as long as the association is in place.

When the object that holds the association (the first parameter to `objc_setAssociatedObject`) deallocs, it will break the association.  When the association is broken, the retained object will be released (if it was retained to begin with).

So, for your example:

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, key, value, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
```

`value` would be retained until the association was broken.  The association would be broken when `self` deallocs or when the association is changed with another `objc_setAssociatedObject`.